# MS Excel - finding the first row after a certain date

Tags: excel, date

Say I have a spreadsheet with the following, and for convenience say all of this starts from cell A1.

```
---------------------------------------
| Date          | Item      | Account |
---------------------------------------
| 01/09/2011    | Testing 1 | USD     |
| 03/09/2011    | Testing 2 | USD     |
| 11/09/2011    | Testing 3 | USD     |
| 20/10/2011    | Testing 4 | JD      |
| 22/10/2011    | Testing 5 | JD      |
| 25/10/2011    | Testing 6 | USD     |
| 03/11/2011    | Testing 7 | USD     |
| 05/11/2011    | Testing 8 | JD      |
---------------------------------------
```

Now, I want to run a report for a month, starting on 1/10/2011 and ending on 31/10/2011. I need to find the first row on or after the starting date, and then get every subsequent row until the end date. If I can figure out how to get the row reference for the first and end dates, then I can figure out the rows in between (obviously!).

I have only been able do these sorts of matches on exact matches ie. no idea how to do 'greater/less than' matches.

How would I go about matching on both the date and the account columns?

Needless to say, this needs to be in a formula.

Answer (score 4):

```
=match(date(2011,10,1),a2:a9,1)+1
=match(date(2011,10,31),a2:a9,1)
```

First formula shows row for the first record for October, second formula for the last day.  Data must be sorted in ascending order.

Comment: Just tested and it works for the data above. But if I modify the data to include 1/10/2011 as one of the dates, then it still adds 1 to the rows and gets the next row.

Comment: Assuming you have Office 2007 or above: =IFERROR(match(date(2011,10,1),a2:a9,0),match(date(2011,10,1),a2:a9,1)+1) should handle the case here 1-Oct-11 in the list

Answer (score 1):

Use the following Array Formula for finding the Row containing the earliest date, which is equal to or greater than the date mentioned in cell C1 (in your case this is 1 October).

```
=MATCH(MIN(IF($A$1:$A$30>=C1,1,9999)*$A$1:$A$30),$A$1:$A$30,0)
```

Date list is in cells A1 to A30. Change the references as required.
Data need not be sorted in ascending or descending order.

Use the following Array Formula for finding the Row containing the latest date which is equal to or less than the date mentioned in cell D1 (in your case this is 31 October). Data need not be sorted in ascending or descending order.

```
=MATCH(MAX(IF($A$1:$A$30<=D1,1,0)*$A$1:$A$30),$A$1:$A$30,0)
```

If you want the earliest and latest dates, use the following Array Formulas.

```
=MIN(IF($A$1:$A$30>=C1,1,9999)*$A$1:$A$30)

=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$30<=D1,1,0)*$A$1:$A$30)
```

All the formulas used above are Array Formulas. To enter an array formula, use Control+Shift+Enter instead of Enter.

Vijaykumar Shetye, Goa, India

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a pivot table for this.  Look at the second link on in the "Excel Templates - Pivot Table" section on [this page](http://www.contextures.com/excelfiles.html#Pivot) on the Contextures site.

Comment: I'm trying to make this simple for someone to use who works in another country - I would like them to be able to create simple date-based reports. My fear with pivot tables is that it adds an extra layer of learning. I might end up using them for my own reporting.